# Materialized View vs Trigger for aggregating data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

I have a TASK table :

```
ID |  NAME  | STATUS |
----------------------
 1 | Task 1 |  Open  |
 2 | Task 2 | Closed |
 3 | Task 3 | Closed |
```

And in my application i constantly query for a count of tasks grouped by status, so I'm looking for a caching solution.

Naturally, I thought of a trigger that automatically updates an aggregation table on any change to the TASKS table

TASK_COUNT table :

```
 OPEN | CLOSED |
----------------
  1   |    2   |
```

But I've read there is also materialized views.

Which is more reccomended for aggregating data? Materialized Views or Triggers?

Important to note that in my actual scenario I have more aggregations than just STATUS, and more tables than just TASK.

Also this is a rapidly evolving table, and I need the aggregated data to be always up to date.

Comment: Why not just use a standard view?

Answer (score 2):

The downside to materialized views is that the data may not be totally current.  As explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/rules-materializedviews.html):

> While access to the data stored in a materialized view is often much faster than accessing the underlying tables directly or through a view, the data is not always current; yet sometimes current data is not needed.

The advantage of materialized views is that they are much simpler to maintain -- basically define and go.  But there can be a lag for updates.

If you need totally current information, then triggers are probably the better solution.